# Generate integer value for date object in php and pass it to WCF service

Tags: php, wcf, date

I have resful WCF service which receives json. Json contains date object like this

```
'date' => "/Date(1472145040829)/"
```

how can I generate current date for this value using php?

Comment: It's a unix timestamp with milliseconds... extract the number, divide by 1000, cast to int

Comment: Or if you want to go the other way, then it's `time() * 1000`

Comment: no it is not because time() * 1000 always returns integer with three zero(000) at the end.

Comment: I know that "/Date(1472145040829)/" = 20‎.‎06‎.‎1970‎ ‎13‎:‎17‎:‎30 but I don't know how

Comment: So you need to generate with that absolute millisecond precision? To the nearest second isn't accurate enough for this WCF service? Then use `(new DateTime())->format('Uu');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is millisecond since [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

You should be able to generate it using [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) like so:

```
//current timestamp in milliseconds since start of epoch
$timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000); 

//generate required format
$string = "/Date($timestamp)/";
```

Comment: No problem @gogagubi -  if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.